# Understanding glClearBuffer* (difference between fixed- and floating point- color buffers)

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

Imagine having a framebuffer color attachment, a texture of format:

```
glTexImage2D(target, 0, GL_RGBA8, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
```

RGBA8, Unsigned byte.

Normally I would use "glClear()" to clear the framebuffer as a whole.
Even with multiple attachments of various formats, using "glClear()" clears all of them

(together with a clear color "glClearColor()")

And it confusingly clears the the RGBA8 (uint) format texture with THAT FLOATING POINT clear color.

So if I want to clear a single fbo attachment one possible option would be to use:

[**glClearBuffer***](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClearBuffer.xhtml)

> The *fv, *iv and *uiv forms of these commands should be used to clear fixed- and floating-point, signed integer, and unsigned integer color buffers respectively.

But which one should I use to clear the RGBA8 uint attachment? I have tried both:

```
glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR,0,new float[4]);
```

and

```
glClearBufferuiv(GL_COLOR,0,new int[4]);
```

And both work.

What would be the correct way of clearing this particular attachment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GL_RGBA8` is a normalized, fixed-point image format. Therefore, you should use the `fv` function.

That being said, the standard says that if the clear buffer function you use is not appropriate for the format of the buffer, you get undefined behavior. But you *don't* get an error.

Undefined behavior can also include "works as I expected".